# measurement of memory usage after each GC for Android

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection

What is the best way to measure memory usage after each garbage collection for Android? I know that there are some GC prints in logcat, but it seems that there is not enough information in Android 2.2 or before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this: listen on logcat prints, and run a `dumpsys meminfo` each time a GC message is spotted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way but I'm using Alocation Tracker from DDMS together with "Cause GC" button. This [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) describes memory analysis with heap dumps.
You can also check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) about tracking memory usage on Android.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to have an automatic way of monitoring memory usage at run-time. Using DDMS to look at the numbers manually does not work when I have a large suite of test cases.